# javafx.fxml.LoadException after clicking on button

Tags: javafx

I started javafx this year and I am trying to run this code to open a new window but when I run my code get a LoadException.

Here is my code

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import domein.DomeinController;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitelbeeldschermController extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML
    private Button btnFrans;
    @FXML
    private Button btnNederlands;
    @FXML
    private Button btnEngels;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMaaknieuweSpeler;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd;
    @FXML
    private Button btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    private DomeinController dc;

    public TitelbeeldschermController(DomeinController dc){
        this.dc = dc;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Titelbeeldscherm.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try{
            loader.load();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            throw  new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void btnMaakNieuweSpelerOnAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MaakNieuweSpeler.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle(dc.getTaal().getText("nieuweSpeler"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
            stage.show();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnMaakNieuweWedstrijdOnAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MaakNieuweSpeler.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("ABC");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
            stage.show();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnBestaandeWedstrijdLadenOnAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnMenuTaalNederlandsAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        dc.setTaal("nl");
        btnFrans.setVisible(false);
        btnEngels.setVisible(false);
        btnNederlands.setVisible(false);
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("accountMaken"));
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setVisible(true);
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("startNieuwSpel"));
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setVisible(true);
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("laadWedstrijd"));
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setVisible(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnMenuTaalEngelsAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        dc.setTaal("en");
        btnFrans.setVisible(false);
        btnEngels.setVisible(false);
        btnNederlands.setVisible(false);
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("accountMaken"));
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setVisible(true);
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("startNieuwSpel"));
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setVisible(true);
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("laadWedstrijd"));
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setVisible(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnMenuLanguageFransAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
        dc.setTaal("fr");
        btnFrans.setVisible(false);
        btnEngels.setVisible(false);
        btnNederlands.setVisible(false);
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("accountMaken"));
        btnMaaknieuweSpeler.setVisible(true);
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("startNieuwSpel"));
        btnMaakNieuweWedstrijd.setVisible(true);
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setText(dc.getTaal().getText("laadWedstrijd"));
        btnBestaandeWedstrijdLaden.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is the code from my fxml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="406.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.MaakNieuweSpelerController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtGebruikersnaam" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="62.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtGeboortedatum" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="144.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblGebruikersnaam" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="66.0" text="Gebruikersnaam: " />
      <Label fx:id="lblGeboortedatum" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="148.0" text="GeboorteDatum: " />
      <Button fx:id="btnMaakNieuweSpeler" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="234.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#maakNieuweSpeler" text="Aanmaken" />
      <Button fx:id="btnAnnuleren" layoutX="304.0" layoutY="234.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Annuleren" text="Annuleren" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/jelle/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjectenI/pazaak-g16/dist/run1805194826/pazaak-g16.jar!/gui/MaakNieuweSpeler.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at gui.TitelbeeldschermController.btnMaakNieuweSpelerOnAction(TitelbeeldschermController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: gui.MaakNieuweSpelerController
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gui.MaakNieuweSpelerController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of an `FXMLLoader` is to create a controller from a class specified in a `fx:controller` attribute by calling that class's no-argument constructor. In other words, since you have `fx:controller="gui.MaakNieuweSpelerController"` in your FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` will effectively try to do

```
Object controller = new MaakNieuweSpelerController();
```

Since your `MaakNieuweSpelerController` class does not have a no-argument constructor, you get an error when you try to load the FXML file.

The simplest fix is to **remove the `fx:controller="gui.MaakNieuweSpelerController"` attribute from `MaakNieuweSpeler.fxml`** and set the controller in Java code:

```
@FXML
public void btnMaakNieuweSpelerOnAction(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MaakNieuweSpeler.fxml"));

        // You didn't post the MaakNieuweSpelerController class, but I am guessing
        // this is how you need to construct it. Just modify this to call 
        // a valid constructor if necessary:
        MaakNieuweSpelerController controller = new MaakNieuweSpelerController(dc);
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);

        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(dc.getTaal().getText("nieuweSpeler"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code and it worked perfectly thank you for all the help